# ASP.NET Core API JWT Authentication: where can I find official documentation on it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, documentation

Where is official documentation on ASP.NET Core API JWT authentication with examples? All I could find were blog posts but no references to MS documentation. Does it exist?

Comment: When you downvote just don't forget to comment what's wrong with my question, ok?

Answer (score 0):

use this link:
[Asp.net core Authentication with JWT](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-authentication-web-f58efc25)